# Derivative of the upper incomplete gamma function.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, gamma-function

I wish to compute the derivative of the upper incomplete gamma function 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(s,x) = \int_{x}^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, dt .
\end{equation}
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Derivatives) states of the derivative of $\Gamma(s,x)$ as 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \Gamma(s,x)}{\partial s} = \ln x \Gamma(s,x) + x \Gamma(3,s,x).
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(K,s,x) = G_{K-1,K}^{K,0} \left(\frac{0,0,\cdots,0}{s-1,-1,\cdots,-1}\mid x\right)
\end{equation}
is the Meijer G function. My question is, if I evaluate this equation at x=0, I should get the psi function but instead I get $-\infty$. Could someone please confirm how to use this, and also clarify if the first term is $\ln (x) \Gamma(s,x)$ or $\ln (x \Gamma(s,x))$.

Thanks.

Comment: The first term is $\ln (x) \times \Gamma(s,x)$

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici. I was able to find the original referred paper and verify this. Also, I think since $\psi(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ from 0+, the stated equation and $\psi(x)$ do give the same result around $x=0$.